# Why do my breakpoints change position when I refresh my page with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breakpoints

Each time I refresh my page, my breakpoint are moved to the end of my script. I have to replace them when the execution is paused, and only then I can debug my script where I want.

This **doesn't** only happen when I change my script, but also every time I reload the page.

And how to solve this problem?

Comment: I am not sure it is an angularjs specific problem.

Comment: I suspect angularjs' dependency injection to cause the problem. Since my browser considers that my script changes, it moves the breakpoints. But I am not sure at all.

Comment: Every time I reload the page.

Comment: Even if you haven't changed the HTML either? That seems *very* strange.

Comment: Yes. I should check if this happens in every browsers, and with all kind of projects, but I don't have time right now :/